# Rails 7 / Capybara with Selenium-Webdrivers fails (unknown keyword: :capabilities)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am struggling with updating selenium / webdrivers for my rails rspec system tests. I used to have the webdriver gem, now it's telling me I need to use selenium-webdriver. I have installed that gem, according to Gemfile.lock it's v 4.12.0 which should be the latest.

The below configuration in rspec/rails_helper.rb however yields an error as follows:

```
Failure/Error:
            def create_bridge(caps:, url:, http_client: nil)
              Remote::Bridge.new(http_client: http_client, url: url).tap do |bridge|
                bridge.create_session(caps)
              end
            end
          
          ArgumentError:
            unknown keyword: :capabilities
```

Configuration in rails_helper.rb:

```
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end

  Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Options.chrome(
      'goog:chromeOptions': { args: %w(window-size=1400,1400) }
    )
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome, options:
  end
```

Any hints? I tried messing around with "desired_capabilities" but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Rails are you using? I had the same problem and upgrading to Rails version 7.0.5 fixed it. In older Rails versions Action Pack used "capabilites" keyword that is deprecated in selenium-webdriver version 4.12.

Comment: AHA! I am on Rails 7.0.4. I will need to update rails in that case then!

Comment: It doesn't work for me, even though my rails version is 7.0.8

Answer (score 4):

The [selenium-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver) gem has [changes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/rb/CHANGES) in the `4.12.0` version which affects the capabilities keyword:

```
4.12.0 (2023-08-31)
=========================
Ruby:
  * Fix bug preventing good error messages in Selenium Manager when stdout empty
  * Fix bug with Firefox not loading net/http library by default (#12506)
  * Remove support for using capabilities in local drivers

BiDi:
  * Released selenium-devtools 0.116.0 (supports CDP v85, v114, v115, v116)
```

### Before

```rb
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
  args: %w[--headless --no-sandbox --disable-gpu],
  binary: ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil),
)

Capybara.register_driver :headless do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    capabilities: capabilities
  )
end
```

### After

```rb
Capybara.register_driver :headless do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    options: capabilities # change keyword
  )
end
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have - if you look at my code example. I now tried yours, and I copied from the selenium.dev website.... still the same error. I changed the "options" line to `options = Selenium::WebDriver::Options.chrome`, and I tried without "options:" at all... error persists.

Comment: I played around more. The error appears EVEN if I do not have any line in rails_helper.rb in my rspec folder...

Comment: And there's zero other files that includes the `capabilities` keyword in your codebase?

Comment: If I search across the repo for the word "capabilities" I can't find anything...

Comment: @tkhobbes Did you update Capybara too?

Comment: yes I am on Capybara 3.39.2. I also am on the latest rspec-capybara (2.18.0)

Comment: should we use ```--headless```  or  ```--headless=new```